# WCF service constructor

Tags: wcf, constructor

Hi have a service constructor for my WCF service. Which should ideally be initialized only once. But I see that the service constructor is being called every few minutes. Is there some timevalue or some other configuration setting which could limit the no. of calls to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Creation of the WCF service class (and hence calling of the constructor) depends upon the services [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) value. Depending upon its [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) (such as PerCall,PerSession, Single) service instances get created.

You can set the value to `Single` which would make the class act similar to a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using a static constructor.

If the constructor needs to initialize non-static attributes, then maybe what you need is a singleton WCF service. WCF services can have different instantiation modes (PerCall, PerSession and **Single**)

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Note that the single instantiation mode won't probably scale.

You can read more about [service instance management here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/3-ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per#Single%20Instance%20mode)

Comment: Where is that service hosted? IIS? Windows Service? If the app AppDomain gets unloaded (i.e.: IIS pool recycling) obviously the service constructor will be called again.